# Java how do i split string by many double quote

Tags: java, android

I want to split that string and i see its so complictaed.

> "GPSTime":"7/10/2014 5:44:23 AM"

Into

```
7/10/2014 5:44:23 AM
```

any help ?

Comment: Is that the entire string you have? (Not something like `{"GPSTime":"7/10/2014 5:44:23 AM", "Latitude":"100", "Longitude":"100"}` for example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Firstly, split by `":"` and then replace last `"` from the date time string.

```
String c= "\"GPSTime\":\"7/10/2014 5:44:23 AM\"";
String x= c.split("\":\"")[1];
System.out.println("final: "+x.replace("\"", ""));
```

Output:

```
08-07 14:54:21.931: I/System.out(20228): final: 7/10/2014 5:44:23 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :

```
String str[]=s.split("\":\"");
```

or you could do this if the start of the string doesn't change :

```
String noDoubleQuotes = yourString.replace("\"", "");
String result = noDoubleQuotes .replace("GPSTime:", "");
```

Comment: That will also split the individual digits of the time though.

Comment: Unless he changed that to `String str[]=s.split("\":\"");`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String string = "\"GPSTime\":\"7/10/2014 5:44:23 AM\"";
    final String begin = "\":\"";
    final String end = "\"";
    final String substring = string.substring(string.indexOf(begin) + begin.length(), string.length() - end.length());

    System.out.println("substring = [" + substring + "]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
String str[]=s.split("\":\"");
```

And then you remove the remaining `"` from your result.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting by white spaces after replacing " with them:

```
s = s.replace("\"", " ");
String str[]=s.split(" ");
```

The array's last elements should then contain your desired values. Note that you may need to trim the specific entries before use.

Answer (score 0):

Split first using : as separator

```
  String str[]=s.split(":");
```

And then choose the right token to split using space as separator

```
  String str2[]=s.split(" ");
```

And then you have the three elements that you need in str2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regular Expression, 
something like:

```
"GPSTime":"(.+)"
```